# Issue with checking a Path and reading the file in Rust

Tags: file, rust, filesystems

I have an issue with trying to check if a file exists and reading it if it exists.

My code:

```rust
use std::{env, fs};
use std::fs::{File, read};
use std::path::Path;
use std::process::exit;

let arg = env::args().next().expect("Please open a file via the command line!");

let path = Path::new(
    &arg
);

if !path.exists() {
    error!("The specified path does not exist!");
    exit(101);
}

let file = read(path).expect("Could not read file!");
let content = String::from_utf8(file).expect("The file does not contain valid characters!");
```

Run the program like this `./program.exe a_vali_file_path.txt`

**Expectation:**
If you run the program with a valid file path as the first argument, the program will check if it exists. If it does, the program reads the file content and just returns.

**What actually happened:**
The program doesn't even really check for the file (it does not panic, even if the path is not valid) and if it tries to read it prints a bunch of bytes into the console followed by the error
`error: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 2, error_len: Some(1) } }`.
This behavior occurs if the file exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

env::args.next() references the executable, which doesn't contain UTF-8 bytes. If you want to point to the next argument you must use another `.next()` call, or better yet use a Vector to store your args.

Example of a vector being used to store args ->

```
fn main() {

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect()

    ...

}
```

To solve it your way:

```
fn main() {

    let args = env::args()
    args.next() //Points to executable (argv[0])
    args.next() //Points to file (argv[1])

}
```

As you can see the second solution is not very elegant, but hey, to each their own.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for wasting your time because of this stupid issue my little brain cells had.

Comment: Don't worry, everyone has moments like this every once in a while.